# Question mark in value of @InjectLink is encoded as %3F. How to prevent this?

Tags: java, jersey, link-header

I use Jersey's Link Headers feature to create HTTP link headers:

`@InjectLink(value="users/?orgId=12345&page=0",rel="first")`

Works well except question mark - this is encoded in %3F and resulting URL looks like:
    `http://localhost:8080/app/users/%3ForgId=12345&page=0`

I there any way to prevent encoding and leave question mark char as is?

Answer (score 1):

It is not suitable case for `@InjectLink(value)`. The URL parameter building should be used by  `@InjectLink(method, bindings...)`.

For example:

```
@InjectLink(
  resource = UserResource.class,
  method ="getUserById", 
  bindings ={@Binding(name = "orgId", value = "${instance.orgId}")},
  style =  Style.ABSOLUTE,
  ... )
```

And target Jersey resource *UserResource.java*:

```
@Path("users/{orgId}") 
public User getUserById(@PathParam("orgId") String orgId) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

question mar is url encoded for query params string, so its normal to have %3 in your path. Try using 'bindings' or puting @Queryparams like this [How to force URIBuilder.path(...) to encode parameters like "%AD"? This method doesn't always encode parameters with percentage, correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431935/how-to-force-uribuilder-path-to-encode-parameters-like-ad-this-method-d/21651223#21651223)