# Query parameter encoding using Jersey client

Tags: jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using Jersey client 2.25.1 and the queryParam(...) method does not correctly encode the values, e.g this approach fails:

```
    Response response = client.target(uri)
            .queryParam("a", "%20") // Translated into space ' '(!)
            .queryParam("b", "{")   // Will ruin template parsing(!)
            .queryParam("c", "}")   // Will ruin template parsing(!)
            .queryParam("d", URLEncoder.encode(" ", "UTF-8")) // Using explicit encoding will translate ' ' into '+'(!)
            .request().get();
```

So the [workaround suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186894/957280) is like this:

```
    Response response = client.target(uri)
            .queryParam("a", "{a}").resolveTemplate("a", "%20")
            .queryParam("b", "{b}").resolveTemplate("b", "{")
            .queryParam("c", "{c}").resolveTemplate("c", "}")
            .queryParam("d", "{d}").resolveTemplate("d", " ")
            .request().get();
```

This works, but it puzzles me that this very common use case doesn't have better library support from the Jersey client(?) I want to be able to have an arbitrary value properly URL encoded as a query parameter, so that exact same value will reach the server side.

Are there alternatives to this solution? Which is the preferred/best way to solve this?